# How to call an external script with arguments?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that should call various scripts when the execution throws an error. How can I call a script with two arguments?

For the moment I am using the code below but I need to also send two arguments to script.sh:

```
my_script = "script.sh"
%x( #{my_script})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost figured it out, just add the params:

```
my_script = "script.sh"
%x( #{my_script} #{arg1} #{arg2})
```

You may also want to check the return code:

```
if $? == 0
   puts "script executed successfully"
else
   puts "script returned an error, exit code: #{$?.to_s.split('exit ')[-1]}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

dimid's way would work in the simplest cases, but it will not work in edge cases.

You need to shell-escape the arguments.

```
require "shellwords"

"command %s %s" % args.map{|arg| Shellwords.escape(arg)}
```